# Is it necessary to stop timers on activity/view/fragment stop?

Tags: android, handler

Is it necessary to stop manually timed tasks (with Handler) when the activity stops / view is detached / etc. Or will the system just remove them?

I have, for example, a Runnable which I use to update a TextView each second. When the user leaves the activity, do I have to call `removeCallbacks(task)`?

I tried both (remove and not) and they work, but I don't know if the timer keeps running unnecessarily or this can lead to exceptions under certain circumstances.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it has to be handled or cancelled., while you are using the Timer Task it should be cancelled before the respective task or activity or app closes., otherwise it will process its content even  after the instance closed too....